# Specify Multiple Folders for Input in Pail Tap Hadoop Jobs

Tags: hadoop, input, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I am running a hadoop mapreduce job using Cascalog API.I want to take multiple input folders to process the map reduce job.

I have two folders in HDFS rooPath/Folder_1 & rootPath/Folder_2 which contains files that are to be processed in a job.

I am giving the job the input folders throught Pail Tap function :

```
new PailTap(rootPath + "Folder_1",
            JcascalogUtils.getPailTapOptions());
```

Can I give multiple folders to the same job.

and Can I give a regex fodler Path like rootPath+*/ so that it will process all the folders in the rootPath folder.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MultiSourceTap like this:

```
dataSource = new MultiSourceTap( 
              new PailTap(rootPath + "Folder_1",JcascalogUtils.getPailTapOptions()),
              new PailTap(rootPath + "Folder_2",JcascalogUtils.getPailTapOptions())
             );
```

or use GlobHfs

```
dataSource = new GlobHfs(new PailTap(rootPath,JcascalogUtils.getPailTapOptions()).getScheme() , rootPath + "*");
```